# for loop append variable php

Tags: php, xml, parsing, for-loop

I have a xml file that i want to echo to the browser

```
echo $rule = $info->rule1

echo $rule = $info->rule2
```

Result:

example 1

example 2

Because the rule in the xml is dynamic i want to count how much rules there are and pass that variable behind the "rule"

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('file.xml');
$xml_nested = $xml->monthlegenda;
echo "<ul>";
foreach ($xml_nested as $info):
    for($i=1; $i < count($info); $i++){
    $rule = $info->rule;
    $rule .= $i;
    echo $rule;
    };
endforeach;
echo "</ul>";
```

As a result i expect:

example 1

example 2

but i get 
12

Comment: Please post your XML also.

Comment: I think your parsing is wrong show your XML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code for "for":

```
for($i=1; $i < count($info); $i++)
{
    $rule = $info->{'rule'.$i};
    echo $rule;
}
```

Comment: There's an issue with this code: you'll not loop through all properties of `$info` (the last one will be skipped), and you're calling `count` on each iteration. Check my answer for details...

Comment: This works thanks!, but how can i make sure i get all the "rule" because i count all childeren i have to "remove the count" for the children that are not "rule"

Comment: @MichaelAngelo: Added the answer to that to the bottom of my answer (it's by using a `foreach` loop: objects _can_ be iterated over using `foreach`)

Answer (score 3):

You're probably looking for a way to get the property of an object from a string, which is done like so:

```
$instance->{$var.'string-part'.$otherVar};
```

In your case, that'd be:

```
echo $info->{'rule'.$i};
```

For more details, refer to [the man pages on variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php). Especially the section entitled *" #1 Variable property"* should be of interest to you...
But since you're echoing `<ul>` tags before and after the loop, I'm assuming you're trying to create a list, in which case, your echo statement should look like this:

```
echo '<li>', $info->{'rule'.$i}, '</li>';//comma's not dots!
```

Note that you'll never loop through the entire `$info` object, because of your `for` loop. You should either write:

```
for ($i=1,$j = count($info);$i<=$j;$i++)
{
    echo $info->{'rule'.$i};
}
```

Note that I'm assigning `count($info)` to a variable, to avoid calling `count` on each iteration of the loop. You're not changing the object, so the `count` value will be constant anyway... or simply use `foreach`:

```
foreach($info as $property => $val)
{//val is probably still an object, so use this:
    echo $info->{$property};
}
```

In the last case, you could omit the curlies around `$property`, but that's not recommended, but what you can do here, is check if the property concerned is a `rule` property:

```
foreach($info as $property => $val)
{
    if (substr($property, 0, 4) === 'rule')
    {//optionally strtolower(substr($property, 0, 4))
        echo '<li>', $info->{$property}, '<li>';
    }
}
```

That's the easiest way of doing what you're doing, given the information you've provided...

Comment: The first solution did show every entry, i tried the foreach but is it nested in the for loop because it does not check all rule's

Comment: @MichaelAngelo: setup a pastebin, or add the `foreach` code to your question, so I can see what you're doing, but using the foreach, you don't need the `for` loop any longer. The `foreach` replaces the `for` loop, but it's still _"nested"_ inside the `foreach($xml_nested as $info)` loop

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
$rule = $info->{rule.$i};
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('file.xml');
$xml_nested = $xml->monthlegenda;
echo "<ul>";
foreach ($xml_nested as $info) 
    for($i=1; $i < count($info); $i++){
    $rule = "";
    $rule = $info->rule;
    $rules =  $rule.$i;
    echo $rules;
    } 
echo "</ul>";
```

Comment: No, that won't make a difference since `$rule` is overwritten with `$info->rule;` in the next statement.